# Is there unique-value / set container in java-script

Tags: javascript, containers

Is there a set (unique-value) container in JS something like std::set in C++?

I need something to put many different values in and at the end obtain a unique list of those values.

Comment: what kind of values? [heres a SO on removing uniques from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array) jquery also [has a method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) to remove duplicates from html collections. there is no inbuilt unique collection, you'd nee dto filter it

Comment: There's one in ECMAScript 6.

Comment: Oh I see, there is an answer already. Thanks!